# Is this "strong correlation" definition valid?

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, spurious-correlation

[This page](http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/tutorial-how-to-detect-spurious-correlations-and-how-to-find-the-) defines a a "strong correlation" using a formula that combines a standard correlation measure with lag-1 autocorrelation measures.

I've never seen a definition of correlation like this before. Is this "strong correlation" measure valid, and does it really help avoid spurious correlations?

Here's the definition of the "strong correlation":

- Define the Weak correlation $c(X, Y)$ as the absolute value of the ordinary correlation, with value between $0$ and $1$. This number is high (close to $1$) if $X$ and $Y$ are highly correlated. I recommend using my rank-based, L-1 correlation to eliminate problems caused by outliers.
- Define $c_1(X)$ as the lag-1 auto-correlation for X, that is, if we have n observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, then $c_1(X) = c(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}, X_2,\ldots, X_n)$
  $c_1(Y)$ as the lag-1 auto-correlation for $Y$
- Define the d-correlation $d(X, Y) = \exp\{ -a * | \ln( c_1(X) / c_1(Y) ) | \}$, with possible adjustment if numerator or denominator is zero, and parameter a must be positive or zero. This number, with value between $0$ and $1$, is high (close to $1$) if $X$ and $Y$ have similar lag-1 auto-correlations.
- Then the Strong correlation $r(X, Y) = \min\{ c(X, Y), d(X, Y) \}$